# Linq from C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, c#-to-vb.net

I'm attemping from C# this LINQ expression, but it does not seem to work

C#

```
var v = (from a in dc.ChatPrivateMessageMasters
                     join b in dc.ChatPrivateMessageDetails on a.EmailID equals b.MasterEmailID into cc
                     from c in cc
                     where (c.MasterEmailID.Equals(fromid) && c.ChatToEmailID.Equals(toid)) || (c.MasterEmailID.Equals(toid) && c.ChatToEmailID.Equals(fromid))
                     orderby c.ID descending
                     select new
                     {
                         UserName = a.UserName,
                         Message = c.Message,
                         ID = c.ID
                     }).Take(take).ToList();
```

VB

```vb
Dim v = (From a In dc.ChatPrivateMessageMasters _
Join b In dc.ChatPrivateMessageDetails On a.EmailID Equals b.MasterEmailID _
Into cc _
From c In cc Where (c.MasterEmailID.Equals(fromid) AndAlso c.ChatToEmailID.Equals(toid)) OrElse (c.MasterEmailID.Equals(toid) AndAlso c.ChatToEmailID.Equals(fromid)) _
Order By c.ID Descending _
Select New With { _
    .UserName = a.UserName, _
    .Message = c.Message, _
   .ID = c.ID _
}).Take(take).ToList()
```

I received an error from 'Into' with message: ')' expected

Any idea?

// update my database structure
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try this [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)?

Comment: Yes, but not useful

Comment: Are you understanding what the intent of the original `into` clause is attempting to do? In Visual Basic, `INTO` is used with aggregation and not just wrapping a previous query.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't need the group join (the `into` part of your `join` clause), considering you flatten it immediately (and don't do a left outer join for example).

Your C# query can simply be:

```
var query =
    (from m in dc.ChatPrivateMessageMasters
    join d in dc.ChatPrivateMessageDetails on m.EmailID equals d.MasterEmailID
    where (d.MasterEmailID == fromid && d.ChatToEmailID == toid)
       || (d.MasterEmailID == toid && d.ChatToEmailID == fromid)
    orderby d.ID descending
    select new
    {
        m.UserName,
        d.Message,
        d.ID
    }).Take(take).ToList();
```

And the VB.net equivalent of that is:

```
Dim query =
    (From m In dc.ChatPrivateMessageMasters
    Join d In dc.ChatPrivateMessageDetails On m.EmailID Equals d.MasterEmailID
    Where (d.MasterEmailID = fromid AndAlso d.ChatToEmailID = toid)
    OrElse (d.MasterEmailID = toid AndAlso d.ChatToEmailID = fromid)
    Order By d.ID Descending
    Select m.UserName, d.Message, d.ID
    Take take).ToList
```

Comment: The code can be further "simplified" ; `Take` clause exists in query syntax for VB.Net and `(From ...).ToList` can be rewritten as `Aggregate ... Into ToList` eliminating all parenthesis (even the ones in the Where aren't needed as AndAlso has priority over OrElse)

Comment: Thank Jeff, I'll try

Comment: @Sehnsucht: Thanks for the tip about the other clauses. In particular, I didn't know `Take` was available.  I wasn't sure how to integrate `Aggregate` into this so I stuck with the `ToList` call at the end. The extra parens on the `Where` clause I agree but to some people it makes it more readable and I wouldn't remove it from a translation if someone else thought it would be helpful.

Comment: @JeffMercado I agree about the conditional that's why I mentioned for info only (put it inside parens). As for clause nearly (if not all) all clauses are available in query syntax for VB.Net (Skip [While] / Take [While], Distinct)